# Sanitizing arrays in select_all SQL queries in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to pull aggregated columns from my database in a way that's unique to this page, crosses several models, and is expensive to aggregate in memory on a page that already has performance concerns. As a result, I want to make a hand-written SQL query to the database and return a bunch of simple objects (like hashes, or structs) which I can then dole out to the existing objects that consume this information. `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all` is perfect for what I want.

My SQL string takes an array of ids:

```
WHERE entry.task_id IN (#{@project.tasks.id})
```

but this doesn't work because it returns a wrapped array, and connection.quote returns *a bulleted list* for some reason. What would be the best way to get the information I want? Should I manually strip off the `[` and `]`? Is there a handy, accessible function like `sanitize_sql_array` that'll do the trick? Should I never be calling select_all as part of normal operation?

This appears to have been easier in the past, but most of the methods I would use have been protected (including `sanitize_sql_array`). Rails *really* wants me to use ActiveRecord query methods, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join and make your array a string, then pass it to the SQL:

```
ids_string = ids.join(', ')
```

Comment: Was that simple. Thanks!